# substring function in c# throwing exception

Tags: c#, string

My string is `delete filename` (filename )which i would give at run time  this string is `str3` I want only the filename(no matter what length it is). Here is my code:

```
int len = str3.Length;
string d = str3.Substring(6,len-1);// 6 for delete index and to get rest word is len -1
Console.Write(d);
```

But It is throwing me an exception.

Comment: (1) Why was this tagged `Java`? (2) what _exactly_ is the input string? (3) what _exactly_ is the exception.

Comment: First, when you say "it is throwing an exception", *always* post the exception information. Secondly, check the second parameter to the `Substring` method, it is not the index to stop at, it is the number of characters to copy. You can't copy that many characters (len-1) from the 6th position in the string.

Comment: I am getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: I will enter delete <filename>(this filename could be any lenght).Now by using substring . I just want filename

Answer (score 4):

`Substring` expects the length of the rest of the string (ie, the number of characters to grab).  Try this:

```
string d = str3.Substring(6, len-7);
```

**EDIT** - As CodeCaster reminded me, if you're grabbing the whole remainder of the string, you don't need to include the length.

```
string d = str3.Substring( 6 );
```

Comment: And you can omit the second parameter, since the behaviour of [`Substring(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) is to include the remainder of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not telling us what the exception is, I'm going to assume that it's from the length being less than the substring starting point. Before you do

```
str3.Substring(6,len-6)
```

you should first check

if (str3.Length > 6)

so it looks like

```
int len=str3.Length;
if (str3.Length > 6)
    string d = str3.Substring(6,len-6);
Console.Write(d);
```

Also note that it's len-6 since that refers to the count, not the last index. The second param for String.Substring also isn't necessary. It goes to the end of the String by default as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
  str3.Substring(6,(len-6));
```

Second argument is number of characters in the substring, so if you start at index 6 and you want everything after that point you would subtract startindex from the length.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the file name, just use the GetFileName method of the Path class in the System.IO namespace:

```
string d = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(str3);
```